# Employ separate returned variables not associated to an instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, self

I am trying to inherit Python Class dict to modify its functionality. I would like it to return a self-determined value when the key is not present (i.e. override ***get*** rather than return None). I can do it using the following snippet but there is a problem:

```
class xDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
        self.out = 0

    def reap(self, qw): #instead of *dict.get()*
        if qw not in self.keys(): return self.out
        else: return self.get(qw)
        
    def modify(self, qw):
        self.out = qw

l = xDict({'c':2,'x':1})
```

When I call `l`, it contains the the 'out' variable associated with the instance: *{'c': 2, 'x': 1, 'out': 0}*

I would like to avoid this being contained in the dictionary - is it possible?

I also tried using a class variable solution:

```
class xDict(dict):
    #class variable
    out = 0
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

    def reap(self, qw):
        if qw not in self.keys(): return xDict.out
        else: return self.get(qw)

    @classmethod #class method
    def set_out(cls, x): #USE cls (equivalent to self)
        cls.out = x

l1 = xDict({'c':2,'x':1})
l2 = xDict({'r':2, 'd':2})
```

But here I cannot set separate return values for each instance. For, example: `l1.set_out("NA")` causes any request to l2 to also return 'NA'

Comment: Why are you doing `self.__dict__ = self`? Do you want to access the dictionary items also by attribute access, e. g. `l.c`? There are other ways to do this.

Comment: If the goal is to have dictionaries that return some default value for non-existent keys, then you may want to have a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: @MichaelButscher OK thanks, removing that line solves the problem. The code comes from these pages on how to inherit from Python (meta) classes - I'm new to this and trying to learn. I don't understand what `l.c` means.

Comment: @user3329732 I see. In such a case, you may find [`collections.UserDict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) useful. It is a class intended to provide a more user-friendly way of subclassing dictionaries.

Comment: @bb1 OK thanks, I'm really trying to understand more about classes.